# Destructuring deep properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently started using ES6's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment syntax and started to get familiar with the concept. I was wondering if it's possible to extract a nested property using the same syntax.

For example, let's say I have the following code:

```
let cagingIt = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'Nick Cage'
  }
};
```

I know I am able to access extract `foo` into a variable by doing:

```
// where foo = { bar: "Nick Cage" }
let { foo } = cagingIt;
```

However, is it possible to extract a deeply nested property, like `bar`. Perhaps something like this:

```
// where bar = "Nick Cage"
let { foo[bar] } = cagingIt;
```

I've tried finding documentation on the matter but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is { bar } = cagingIt.foo; insufficient?

Comment: @RobFoley definitely a good way to go about it, but was more curious about whether the syntax supported the destructuring of deeply nested properties.

Comment: You sure do like Nicholas Cage.

Comment: Agree with @Dom. I was hoping for a solution that exists in Mongo like
**foo.$.bar**

Comment: Why do I always forget this and have to keep coming back to this post :/

Answer (score 152, accepted):

There is a way to handle nested objects and arrays using this syntax. Given the problem described above, a solution would be the following:

```
let cagingIt = {
      foo: {
        bar: 'Nick Cage'
      }
    };
let { foo: {bar: name} } = cagingIt;

console.log(name); // "Nick Cage"
```

In this example, `foo` is referring to the property name "foo". Following the colon, we then use `bar` which refers to the property "bar". Finally, `name` acts as the variable storing the value.

As for array destructuring, you would handle it like so:

```
let cagingIt = {
      foo: {
        bar: 'Nick Cage',
        counts: [1, 2, 3]
      }
    };

let { foo: {counts: [ ct1, ct2, ct3 ]} } = cagingIt;
console.log(ct2); // prints 2
```

It follows the same concept as the object, just you are able to use array destructuring and store those values as well.

Comment: Neat, I poked at the Babel repl for a bit, but didn't try that syntax.

Comment: An example of something similar is in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring

Comment: Gets really crazy when you use computed property names alongside deep destructuring.

Comment: Another weird way is let { ['foo']: {['bar']: name} } = cagingIt;

Comment: Consider that destructuring is not null-safe so it is risky to use this way.

Comment: how can I destructure using a variable which contains a string?
eg: const { string_variable:  some_var } = object  (in the case of deep properties)

Comment: I wonder how it would work for arrays. With arrays the order of 'keys' is known, so I'm guessing it's possible to do `[ [ x1, y1 ], [ x2, y2] ] = [ [ 50, 100 ], [ 20, 60] ];`?

Comment: Can or how can you destruct both the parent and child object at the same time? In the example above, how to get foo.bar?

Comment: @newman - I wondered the same. Try this:
`let { foo, foo: { counts, counts: [ct1, ct2, ct3]  } } = cagingIt`

Answer (score 4):

You can destructure a property "*as*" something else:

```
const { foo: myFoo } = { foo: 'bar' }  // myFoo == 'bar'
```

Here `foo` was destructured as `myFoo`. You can also destructure an object "*as*" a destructured object

```
const { foo: { bar } } = { foo: { bar: 'baz' } } // bar == 'baz'
```

Only one variable was defined in each situation, `myFoo` and `bar`, and you can see how they are in similar locations as well, except `bar` has the `{ }` around it.

You can do this for as many layers of nesting as you like, but if you aren't careful going too many level deep you'll get the old `"Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'foo')"`.

```
// Here's an example that doesn't work:
const foo = { bar: { notBaz: 1 } };
const { 
    bar: { 
        baz: { // baz is undefined in foo, so by trying to destructure it we're trying to access a property of 'undefined'
            qux
        }
    }
} = foo;
// throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baz')
// because baz is 'undefined'

// Won't run due to error above
console.log(qux);
```

In this case it should be obvious that we shouldn't be trying to destructure it because we can see the definition of `foo` on the previous line doesn't define the property `baz`. If the object is coming from an API, though, you aren't always guaranteed that every nested property of your *expected* result will be non-`null` or not `undefined` and you can't know beforehand.

You can set a default value for a destructured object by adding `= {}`:

```
const { foo: myFoo = 'bar' } = { baz: 'qux' };  // myFoo == 'bar'
const { bar: { baz } = {} } = { qux: 'quuz' }   // baz == undefined 
// baz is destructured from the object that was set as the default for foo, which is undefined
// this would throw without the default object, as were trying to destructure from 'undefined'
```

You can do this for deeply nested destructurings:

```
// Here's an example that works:
const foo = { bar: { notBaz: 1 } };
const { 
    bar: { 
        baz: {
            qux    // you can default the final item to anything you like as well including null or undefined, but it will be undefined in this case
        } = {}     // if 'baz' undefined, return {}
    } = {}         // if 'bar' undefined, return {}
} = foo;

console.log(qux); // logs 'undefined'
```

If any property is `null` or `undefined` along the way, it will cause a cascade of returning empty objects, whose properties to be destructured at the next level will just be `undefined`. This gets out of hand really quickly though with deeper objects, which can be many lines of code with this formatting. Here's another option that does the same exact thing.

```
const foo = { bar: { notBaz: 1 } };
const {qux} = foo?.bar?.baz ?? {}; // optional chaining and nullish coalescing
```

If at any point along the way `foo`, `bar`, or `baz` is null or `undefined` or `null`, it will return an empty object that you can destructure( the empty object after `??`.

It doesn't make much sense to use destructuring on `{ qux }` if you only need to extract one property, though, because this also requires us to add the nullish coalesced value `?? {}`. Below is probably better.

```
const foo = { bar: { notBaz: 1 } };
const { qux, quux, quuz } = foo?.bar?.baz ?? {}; // this method is better for multiple properties
const quxFromBaz = foo?.bar?.baz?.qux;          // this method is better for single properties
```

For me personally, I think it looks a little messy to include all the optional chaining question marks, but it's better than the alternative with nested destructuring and default values at every level.

And it works with arrays

```
const foo = { 
    bar: [
        { a: 1 }, 
        { b: 2 }
    ] 
}
const c = foo?.bar?.[2]?.c   // c == undefined
// bar[2] will be undefined, so trying to access property 'c' would normally throw an error
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have lodash installed, you can use one of the following:

**_.get**

```js
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
```

or if you need multiple keys.

**_.at**

```js
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }, 4] };

_.at(object, ['a[0].b.c', 'a[1]']);
// => [3, 4]
```

You can also safely pair `_.at()` up with with Array destructuring. Handy for json responses.

```js
[title, artist, release, artwork] = _.at(object, [
  'items[0].recording.title',
  'items[0].recording.artists[0].name',
  'items[0].recording.releases[0].title',
  'items[0].recording.releases[0].artwork[0].url'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

****Three Levels Deep****

In case this helps anyone, here's a bit of code that shows how to destructure three levels deep. In this case, I'm using the `find()` method on an array.

```
const id = someId
array.find(({ data: { document: { docId }, }, }) => docId == id)
```

Above, the array data is structured like this (each obj in the array is the same shape):

```
[{ 
   isSuccess: true, 
   isLoading: false,
   data: {
      foo: bar,
      ...,
      document: {
         docId: '123',
         ...
      },
}}]
```