# Property does not exist on type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to delete the property using destructuring. I am facing one error Property 'student.name' does not exist on type '{ student: { name: number; lastName: number; }; total: number; }'. It does exist but it still complains it does not exist. I am trying to understand why it is giving this error. Below is the code

```js
const studentObj = {
  student: {
    name: 10,
    lastName: 20,
  },
  total: 50
}


const {['student.name']: value, ...newObj} = studentObj //error
```

Comment: You can't get the `rest` syntax to to delete a property in nested scenarios. You could do `const { student: { name, ...rest }, ...rest2 } = studentObj ` but you'd still have to reconstruct the object.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211272/8681416

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring in the following way

```
const { name } = studentObj.student
```

For deleting you can use the following

```
delete studentObj.student.name
```

Comment: *"I am trying to delete the property using destructuring"*

Comment: Updated the answer for delete

Comment: I want to avoid the mutable operations and destructuring overcome this problem. Can we do this using destructuring?

Comment: `const { student, ...rest } = studentObj` Here `rest` will not have the `student` property. I think they are trying to do this with nested object. Not use the delete operator and mutate the original object

Comment: @adiga agreed. Let me try your solution.

Comment: @JN_newbie you seem to have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - don't focus on *destructuring*, as that's the wrong approach. You should ask how to remove a property in an immutable fashion.

Comment: @JN_newbie that was an example for a simple object, not a nested object and it will not work for you

Comment: @adiga I was about to answer this. Yes it will not work.

Comment: how can I remove a property from nested object in an immutable way? as also suggested by @VLAZ